# Getting error in validate_operand "a {obj} was passed".format(obj=type(obj))

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Tried merging 2 tables - df and a_status with the following code (using pandas):

```
df.merge('a_status', how='left', left_on='EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', right_on='employee_number')
```

Tables types are `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`
Data types for the key columns are object (thought the actual content there is int)

This is the error I got:

> line 1993, in validate_operand
>       "a {obj} was passed".format(obj=type(obj))
>   TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a  was passed

Comment: Have you tried `df.merge(a_status, how='left', left_on='EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', right_on='employee_number')`? It seems that you have a typo problem.

Comment: You're welcome ;D I've posted as an answer now, please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Dataframe.merge()` accepts as first argument another dataframe but not a string as shown in your example.

Try the snippet below, it should solve your issue.

`df.merge(a_status, how='left', left_on='EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', right_on='employee_number')`